# Why is time formatting inconsistent between `date` and `thunderbird`?

Tags: date, locale, thunderbird

`locale` shows “en_NZ.utf8” everywhere, and `date` produces output like “Thu Nov 22 08:39:49 NZDT 2018”. So the clock is 24 hours, as expected. But while Thunderbird 60.3.1's “Date and Time Formatting” is set to “Regional settings locale: English (New Zealand)” it shows datetimes like “22/11/18 3:36 pm”. Is there a bug in the Thunderbird locale settings?

Comment: Which version of Thunderbird?  You may be encountering [Setting date locale no longer works in Thunderbird 60 on linux](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1426907) ("Status: Unconfirmed").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is Thunderbird bug:

[1426907: Setting date locale no longer works in Thunderbird 60 on linux (LC_TIME=en_DK.utf8 behaves differently than it used to)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1426907)

Comment: The bug was reported a year ago, and after several Status changes, it's still "Unconfirmed" with the discussion ongoing, and the full thread links to several similar bugs.  So I can't really summarize it better than the title already does :(

Comment: In case someone wants to have ISO 8601 date format in Thunderbird without waiting years for the bug to be fixed, I was able to make it display YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM 24-hour format in Thunderbird 68.10.0 by setting LC_TIME="lt_LT.UTF-8" Displays all as digits, no Lithuanian words displayed. Thanks Lithuania, I spent a lot of time going though various countries locales to find you!